# Using whole page with minipages

Tags: minipage

I'm preparing template for dynamic content. Content will be printent in blocks, as presented here:

[image]

Page format a4, no margins. Special printer provided. There are 21 blocks. Each block size: 70mm x 42 mm.

I'm struggling with 7th row with keeps missing. I'm using minipage with size given above for each block. The fact that 7th row keeps missing tells that there is at least one vertical spacing on the page. I set all spacing according to: 
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins
at 0 size (top margin set to -1in) but there is no result.

Any idea what's missing ? 
Or is there any other way to use 7x42mm = 294mm of page's 297mm space ?

Comment: Hi and welcome, missing is some code to reproduce and understand your  case. Please add a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a primitive model to be served as a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in,top=1.5mm,bottom=1.5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \foreach \x in {1.5,43.5,...,295.5}{
     \draw[very thick,blue] ([yshift=-\x mm]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\x mm]current page.north east);
     }
     \foreach \x in {0,70,140,210}{
     \draw[very thick,blue] ([shift={(\x mm,-1.5mm)}]current page.north west) -- ([shift={(\x mm,1.5mm)}]current page.south west);
     }
\node[scale=10,text=blue!70!black,font=\sffamily] at (current page.center) {21};)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of coding specfic widths it is better to set the width of the `minipage` to be `0.33\linewidth` and the height to be `0.14\textheight`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\MyContent}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed nunc nec urna semper faucibus et eu dui. Fusce et dui eu justo ultricies facilisis. Mauris tincidunt non nisi vitae venenatis. Praesent viverra congue euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut id justo turpis. Praesent fringilla, nisi ornare pretium ultrices, tortor felis mattis dui, quis iaculis massa\ldots%
}

\newcommand*{\MyMinipage}[1]{%
\fboxsep=0pt%
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t][0.14\textheight]{0.33\linewidth}
    #1\strut%
\end{minipage}}%
}

\begin{document}
\MyMinipage{1. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{2. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{3. \MyContent}%

\MyMinipage{4. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{5. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{6. \MyContent}%

\MyMinipage{7. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{8. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{9. \MyContent}%

\MyMinipage{10. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{11. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{12. \MyContent}%

\MyMinipage{13. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{14. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{15. \MyContent}%

\MyMinipage{16. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{17. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{18. \MyContent}%

\MyMinipage{19. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{20. \MyContent}%
\MyMinipage{21. \MyContent}%
\end{document}
```